# Dell XPS 15z Wireless (Centrino N 6230) Intermittent Slow-downs

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

**Problem Description and Background**

Once every second or third page load, my wireless internet connection seems to lag out for about 10-15 seconds and then finally, the page loads. It's making me feel like I'm back in the dial up days with a 56k modem.

I've seen all the known issues with this particular wifi card on the ubuntu community wiki. None of those potential solutions worked for me. For reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z

Here is all the relevant debug information, if you require more to assist in troubleshooting, please comment and I will update the question with an answer.

**Information**

- Dell XPS 15z
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Centrino N-6230 Wireless Card

**Details / Read-outs**

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 88:53:2e:5c:93:fb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-34-generic-pae firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:24 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 84:8f:69:b2:62:ca
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:f1800000-f183ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

---

```
$ rfkill list all
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
9: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
11: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
```

---

Comment: The fix in the answers to the question noted above solved my issue.